# delete/free performance variation

Tags: c++, free

I developed an application that open and process files under Qt Creator with Qt 5.5 and MSVC 2013, under windows 7.

I have seen some weird lag on my application: when I open a file, it takes 5 seconds. Relaunch the app, it takes more than 1 minutes. Relaunch: 5 seconds.

It seems random, and when I profiled my app (with Very Sleepy CS), I saw that delete took 0.03 seconds of the total 130 seconds, and free took 124 seconds, and new 3 seconds.

I use some new array[] and delete [] in my code.
I don't know what can cause this kind of bug... The other opened programs didn't even changed.

Any advise / idea?

EDIT: Let's be more precise:
I want to know if something could cause free to be randomly efficient/ ineficient.
I profiled my app and the bottleneck is free.
I don't call directly free because I use delete [].
I need to use delete [] to work on array which are the fastest way in my case and performance is very important.

Comment: The advice is to show the code. Or to profile it. Or break into a debugger when application wait for something too long.

Comment: I already profiled it and I saw free took 95% of the running time...

Comment: Advice... yes, 1) don't use `malloc`/`free` in C++ if you can help it, and 2) prefer a smart pointer (`auto_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, etc.) instead of `new`/`delete`.

Comment: I use delete, not free, but delete calls free.
And if I use an unique_ptr, it will call delete which calls free and free will still be slow, in my logic.

Comment: You are assuming `unique_ptr` will cause the same behavior. Most likely there is a flaw in your allocation and deallocation logic that causes this behavior, and a smart pointer would help that scenario. Another tip, try to use `std:vector` or other STL container for arrays.

Comment: Well, delete shouldn't be doing anything too length aside from calling all of the dtors. Are you using a user defined type? What is the dtor doing?

Comment: And I second the `std::vector` vote. Sometimes when working with intrinsics I've used `_aligned_malloc` but even then I'll wrap it in a unique_ptr.

Comment: If you can, reuse the memory.  A technique in embedded systems is to allocate an array at the beginning of the program and pass pointers to it; instead of allocating, deleting, allocating, deleting, etc.  This technique also reduces the effects of fragmentation on your program.

Comment: Without knowing what you repeatedly alloc and free, hard to say. But I once worked on machines having as little as 640Mo RAM, and learned that fragmenting the heap was bad. The worse is allocate 2 blocs, free first and allocate a larger one. There is no garbage collector in C++, but if you use too much memory (including heap gaps), you could start swapping on disk. You should say more on you new[] delete[] usage...

Answer (score 0):

Advice: Something is wrong here. Something is not working the way it is supposed to work. There have been some suggestions for micro-optimisations, but that isn't going to help, until you figure out what is happening.

If you can open that file in five seconds, then it shouldn't take more a second time. It's possible that it is the other way round, if you read a 2GB file and the second time it's all cached in RAM. But not what you are experiencing.

Possibilities are for example accessing a server over a bad network connection, or some undefined behaviour, like

```
size_t size; // Forgot to initialise
void* p = malloc (size);
memset (p, 0, size);
free (p);
```

might take no time at all once, and 130 seconds another time. Your app might use multithreading and get itself into a bad state sometimes where no progress is made for ages.

I'd just launch the app, break into the debugger after 60 seconds, and check what the hell it is doing :-) Or use a profiler :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions !
Qt is highly multithreaded and I also use one or two thread, it is possible that it falls into a bad state.